# How to plot a function that depends on a solution to a numerical equation?

Tags: plotting, numerics

Consider a function

H[q(t),r(t)] = (1/2)(f[r(t)]-f[q(t)]),

where f(x) is known, r(t) depends on q(t), and q(t) is a solution of a numerical equation.

Question: How do I plot H(t)?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Would you please load the Mathematica code (not images) for functions and make this question concrete enough to answer? Thanks.

Comment: Use `ParametricPlot`